# Nginx + php — Проблема параллельного выполнения скриптов

Tags: php, nginx

На борту nginx-1.15.2, php 7.2
столкнулся с проблемой написания poll сервера, со стороны клиента идет обращение при помощи ajax к скрипту, в скрипте идет ожидание ответа от сокета другого tcp локального сервера(30-40 секунд), сам процесс работает на ура, но вот проблема в том пока идет обмен между клиент/сервером, другие клиенты ожидают окончание выполнения этого скрипта что бы подгрузить любую страничку 
Так же была произведена попытка одновременного запуска 2-ух скриптов с разными именами, но с одинаковым кодом

```
test.php
<? sleep(10); echo "end."; ?>
```

и как выяснилось они выполняются последовательно
Вот основной код:

```
index.php
function api(name, data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',                   
        url: '../api.php?api='+name,      
        data: data,
        success: function(data){callback(data);},
        timeout: 60000
    });
}

function start_poll_server() {
    api("startpolling", {"t": t}, function (response){
        if (response != "") {
            res = JSON.parse(response);
            if (typeof res.response != "undefined")
            {
                for (key in res.response.l) {
                    $('#log').append(res.response.l[key]+"\r\n"); 
                }
                t = res.response.t;
            } else $('#log').append("Poll server error JSON: "+response+"\r\n"); 
        }
        start_poll_server();            
    });
}

api.php
session_start();
...
if (session_write_close() === false) GenError(501, "session_write_close error");
...
if ($api == "wresthost.api.core.startpolling") {
    if (isset($_POST["t"])) {
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
        if ($socket === false) GenError(501, "socket_create() failed, reason: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error()));

        $result = @socket_connect($socket, "127.0.0.1", 8000);
        if ($result === false) GenError(501, "socket_connect() failed, reason: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)));

        $in = GenRequest($api, array("t" => "{$_POST['t']}"));
        @socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
        $result = "";
        $out = "";
        while ($out = @socket_read($socket, 2048)) $result.=$out;
        socket_close($socket); 
        GenResponse(json_decode($result));
    } else GenError(501, "arg \"t\" not found");    
}
```

Comment: ` async: true,` добавьте в ajax. Если не поможет, приведите минимальный код и конкретно опишите проблему.Много лишней информации.

Comment: а разве async не по дефолту в true?
если в вкратце, то скрипты вызванные со стороны клиента, выполняющиеся по 30-40 секунд не дают другим клиентам выполнение любых других скриптов по окончанию первого

Comment: Вы описывайте слишком общую проблему.Если вам помочь то придется весь ваш процесс продебажить. Это может быть и из за заполнения канала .То есть ваш скрипт сжирает всю память и пока не освободит другие не могут им пользоваться.

Comment: Так была попытка выполнения двух тестовых скриптов test.php код которого указал выше и он тоже блокирует, может проблема сама в сервере?

Comment: Все может быть, понимаете здесь вам никто точно не сможет ответить.Будут лишь предположения.Если грешите на сервер, протестте его, или переведите на apache.

Comment: Проблема таилась в конфиге сервера, а точнее увеличение количества upstream бекендов